# Making divs on my page responsive

Tags: php, html, css, responsive

First off. Yes, I have read multiple posts with the same questions, but none of them worked for me. 
I will try to post as much information as I can provide, that relates to the problem. And why I can't fix it myself.

I am making a hosting service website design and I am trying to create boxes, that will include the prices and what we offer. I haven't finished the design on these boxes since I am concentrating too much on the responsiveness of the page.

This is the problem that I am encountering: https://i.gyazo.com/84050e458f93acf0ddefdb189bc886c0.mp4

Here is my CSS:

```
#packages h2 {
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

#package1 {
position: absolute;
top: 85vw;
left: 25vw;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
margin-left: 1px;
margin-right: 1px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 300px;
padding-bottom: 500px;
background-color: #8DB255;
}

#package2 {
position: absolute;
top: 85vw;
left: 50vw;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
margin-left: 1px;
margin-right: 1px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 300px;
padding-bottom: 500px;
background-color: #8DB255;
}

#package3 {
position: absolute;
top: 85vw;
left: 75vw;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
margin-left: 1px;
margin-right: 1px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 300px;
padding-bottom: 500px;
background-color: #8DB255;
}
```

And here is the HTML Code:

```
 <section id="packages">
    <div id="bg_image2">
    </div>
    <ul>
        <div id="package1">
            <h2>
                <?php echo $package1_title; ?>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="package2">
                <h2>
                    <?php echo $package2_title; ?>
                </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="package3">
            <h2>
                <?php echo $package3_title; ?>
            </h2>
        </div>
    </ul>
</section>
```

If needed, here is the PHP file with  the text:

```
// PACKAGES CONFIG
$package1_title = "1GB";
$package2_title = "3GB";
$package3_title = "5GB";
```

Also be patient, since I am not that good. I have heard that the problem is my paddings and margins etc.. Since I just threw in the code and since it worked I didn't think of it. 
But now in the long-run. I have encountered many errors due to my thinking in the beginning.

If you need more information, please do ask. I will try to provide more code and information if necessary.

Comment: the main issue is absolute position ... you are using a bad way to create your layout by making your content out of the flow ... you are looking for 3 column design i guess so look how to do it simply

Comment: You may want to take a look at how Bootstrap implements this in one of their new examples: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/pricing/

Comment: Tieson, perfect example! Thank you. Also thanks Temani, I will look at it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/cqLLa20n/ I created a fiddle with what you want. And also you don't need any of the absolute positions you have there. You should learn the basics

```
<html>
<body>
<section id="packages">
    <div id="bg_image2">
    </div>
    <div id="list">
        <div id="package1">
            <h2>
                1gb
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="package2">
                <h2>
                   2gb
                </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="package3">
            <h2>
               5gb
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

is there a reason you are moving it to the top in respect of your view width?
I personally would just use padding to move it. instead of having to move it to the top and then to the left and then transform ->

```
package x {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 25vw; //whatever ratio you need it to be centered
```

}

Good Luck!!